# Get id after insert and save it as value into another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am programming an App and I have a problem now.

When I register a new student with the app a Query runs on my php Script and insert the new student in my database.

What I want to do now is, when I am registering him, I want my php Script to run a multiple query so that all the other tables should be filled with `NULL` and the query should get the `ID` from the new created student to link it with the other tables(foreign key).

I tried it with `mysqli_multiple_query` and `LAST_INSERT_ID()` but both didn't work.

**How would it be possible to get that id in return from my insert?**

Here is my php script.

```
<?PHP

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {
        $Name     = $_POST['Name'];
        $Surname  = $_POST['Surname'];
        $Street   = $_POST['Street'];
        $Hometown = $_POST['Hometown'];

        if ($Name == '' || $Surname == '' || $Street== '' || $Hometown == '') {
            echo 'please fill all values';
        } else {
            require_once('dbConnect.php');

            $sql  = "INSERT INTO T_Student(Name,Surname,Street,Hometown) VALUES('$Name','$Surname','$Street','$Hometown')";
            $sql .= "INSERT INTO T_University(ID, Teacher, Subject , Classroom, F_ID_Student) VALUES ("","","","","",LAST_INSERT_ID())";


            if(mysqli_multi_query($con,$sql)){
                echo 'successfully registered';
            } else {
                echo 'oops! Please try again!';
            }
        }
        mysqli_close($con);
    }
    echo "Data Inserted";
?>
```

I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Don't concatenate the two queries. Execute the first, save the last id into a variable like

```
$id = mysqli_insert_id();
```

, then execute the second query referencing the variable among the values.

Be aware that if those `$_POST` variables come from a user submitted form it would be useful to do some validation on them before saving them into database. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22311866/1090867) answer would be a nice read ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have modify your code. Try and see if it works for you.

```
<?php

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {
        $Name     = $_POST['Name'];
        $Surname  = $_POST['Surname'];
        $Street   = $_POST['Street'];
        $Hometown = $_POST['Hometown'];

        if ($Name == '' || $Surname == '' || $Street== '' || $Hometown == '') {
            echo 'please fill all values';
        } else {
            require_once('dbConnect.php');

            $sql = "INSERT INTO T_Student(Name,Surname,Street,Hometown)VALUES('$Name','$Surname','$Street','$Hometown')";
            mysqli_query($con, $sql);

            $id = mysqli_insert_id($con);

            if ($id) {
                $sql = "INSERT INTO T_University(ID, Teacher, Subject , Classroom, F_ID_Student) VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, $id)";
                mysqli_query($con, $sql);
            }
        }
        mysqli_close($con);
    }
    echo "Data Inserted";
?>
```

Comment: do you have another idea?

Comment: First, try and check if the id is returned. If yes then the problem will be with your table structure.